# Should I make external API calls in django model managers

Tags: django, api, model

I have local django models that mirror some external service's entities. So basically when I create a local object, I start with making post requests to the service and then fill fields of the local object with the data from response and save it.

Is it a good idea to put external api calls to model manager in order to abstract the logic for views and tests? Or is there a better approach?

What I would like to achieve is to avoid duplicate logic everywhere in the codebase.

Answer (score 3):

Model manager seems to be a nice idea. But maybe its better to put those logic for external api calls in a separate class. For example:

```
class ExternalApiService(object):
    model = ModelName

    def create_object(self, **kwargs):
        # create model object
        self.model.objects.create(**kwargs)

    def call_external_api(self):
        # returns json response from API

    def process_api_response(self, json_response):
        # process response

    def get_latest_object(self):
        # get latest object

    def get_object(self, pk):
        # get object
```

And use them in views.

```
service = ExternalApiService()

class SomeView(ListView):
    queryset = service.get_queryset()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SomeView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['something_specific'] = service.get_latest_object()
        return context
```

Advantage of having this layering is to separate models and views from business logic and external services. Also gives more flexibility, because you can access external api from the Service Class Object without having access to the Model or dependency on the Model.